# HTML not updating when changing ng-model programatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-scope

I have a modal that has a form that should popup when the user hits a button. This form contains information from the current user, and the fields should update according to its data. The problem is, they aren't. They appear empty, even though the ng-model variables have different values.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3 class="modal-title">Edit Profile</h3>
</div>
<div data-ng-controller="EditProfileCtrl">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-group" name="editProfileForm" id="editProfileForm" novalidate>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" ng-model="editProfileInfo.id" ng-value="editProfileInfo.id" />
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" ng-model="editProfileInfo.firstname" ng-value="editProfileInfo.firstname" />
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" ng-model="editProfileInfo.lastname" ng-value="editProfileInfo.lastname" />
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="editProfileInfo.email" ng-value="editProfileInfo.email" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="closeModal()">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="editProfile()">Edit Profile</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the Angular Controller:

```
angular.module('uiPoimmo')
.controller 'EditProfileCtrl', ($scope,$http,$route,$rootScope,ModalFactory,UserFactory) ->
  $scope.editProfileInfo = {}
  $scope.error = null

  $scope.openModal = ->
    ModalFactory.open('sm','editprofilemodal.html')
    userInfo = $rootScope.user
    $scope.editProfileInfo.id = userInfo.id
    $scope.editProfileInfo.firstname = userInfo.firstname
    $scope.editProfileInfo.lastname = userInfo.lastname
    $scope.editProfileInfo.email = userInfo.email
```

The ModalFactory opens the modal (working) and the UserFactory contains functions that send requests to a server.

I've tried using $scope.$apply() and also wrapping all the assignments in a function and send it as parameter to $scope.apply()...neither worked. I've also tried changing the values when the user logs in through a broadcast, but it didn't work as well.

Any insights of what could be going on?

**UPDATE:**

index.html

```
<!-- Code Before -->

<li class="dropdown spaced">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">MyName<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <!-- Ignore these changes, just leave yours -->
      <a ng-controller="EditProfileCtrl" ng-click="openModal()">Profile</a>
      <a ng-click="open('sm')">Saved Searches</a>
      <a ng-click="open('sm')">My Estates</a>
      <a ng-controller="CreateEstateCtrl" ng-click="open('lg')">Create Estate</a>
      <a ng-click="open('sm')">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

<!-- Code After -->

<div ng-view=""></div>

<!-- Scripts -->

<!-- Modal outputs here, just before the closing body tag -->    

</body>
```

Modal Factory:

```
angular.module('uiPoimmo')
  .factory 'ModalFactory', ($uibModal,$modalStack) ->
    open: (size, template) ->
      return $uibModal.open(
        animation: true
        templateUrl: "views/#{template}"
        size: size
      )
```

Comment: It was just to avoid using $rootScope.user.something after the equal signs everytime

Comment: Remove ng-value from the input fields. ng-model is enough to map the correct value to the value of the field. There is no reason to bind the same variable twice

Comment: I had it already like that, but it didn't work either

Comment: The problem that I'm *guessing at*, based on the intent of the page and the controller, is that this HTML for the modal is inside a larger HTML page, which also has the `EditProfileCtrl` (using it to call `$scope.openModal`).  The second declaration of the controller in the Modal HTML is in fact creating a second copy of the controller, not using the values set from the parent view.

Comment: That actually makes lots of sense...what would be better...to remove the controller from the modal or split methods among different controllers?

Comment: without seeing the `ModalFactory` code, it's difficult to offer a concrete solution to this problem.  I suspect that you don't actually need the controller declared in the modal HTML, but it would be necessary to see where the modal ends up in the DOM tree to know for sure what controller `$scope` it actually exists in.

Comment: I updated the question. I'm thinking on creating a new Controller just for modals and then I won't have the same controller twice. I'll post here if it either works or doesn't

Comment: well that definitely won't work, since in this code, the `ng-controller` that is being used to call `openModal()` is on the `<a>` tag.  That is a rather unorthodox practice, as the controller affects an element and the contents of the element;  usually a `<div>` or other block element that can have inner elements is a better choice.  In this case, that `<a>` tag is calling a function that changes a model that would only be relevant if bound to that same `<a>`.